# How to rebrand RCP application for BIRT report designer?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, birt

I'm pretty new to RCP applications + BIRT so I actually don't know where to start with this one.

My goal is to be able to create a designer similar to the RCP Designer for BIRT (http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads). However, I need to change the splash screen, logos, etc. (in short, branding). From this post (http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/261312/), I know that I'm supposed to get the SOURCE code of BIRT and... basically go from there.

However, where do I start? I know this is pretty much a noob's question but I have been searching how I can play around with the branding for the BIRT source but I can't seem to find a decent post about how to do this. There are over a hundred plugins/packages in the source and I seem to see the bits and pieces of where things I should be modifying are but I can't seem to figure out how to piece it together. Worse, the "Integration/Build" section in the docs tell that I should use a Java app run config to start the application when I was thinking it should be a product config file...

Hence, do I create a new RCP application and create extension points (I'm using RCP 3.x not 4.x)...? If so, which ones (plugins/packages) do I need to import for just the designer (not the designer engine... the designer RCP)? Then I'll create the product config from there?

If not, is there a way to just modify directly the source and get the logos and other images to load from there?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Been reading the docs and some e-books... but I'm getting lost as to where I'm supposed to start for what seems to be an easy task :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints:

1. Download the BIRT RCP Application.
2. Open a Standard Eclipse SDK and set the BIRT RCP Application as target platform
3. Open the plugins view
4. Navigate to bundle `org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.rcp` rightclick -> Import as -> Source project
5. Change branding - you can edit now the product file, the manifest, etc...
6. Export again.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it now... after a few trials :D Much appreciated!